# Remove smiles from string in-place

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

I have a coding task. Remove smiles from string in-place. Smile is a set of characters starting from ':' and ending with one or more brackets ')' or one or more brackets '('

**Example**

```
Input "AA:)))( :(("
Output "AA("
```

Could you please review my solution? (My tests are OK, but I want to confirm that everything is OK)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>


using namespace std;


string remove_smiles(string s) {
    int insert_idx = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == ':' and i + 1 < s.size() and (s[i + 1] == ')' or s[i + 1] == '(')) {
            int j = i + 1;
            char smile_mode = s[j];
            while (j < s.size() and s[j] == smile_mode) {
                ++j;
            }
            i = j - 1;
        } else {
            s[insert_idx++] = s[i];
        }
    }
    s.resize(insert_idx);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    assert(remove_smiles("") == "");
    assert(remove_smiles(":)") == "");
    assert(remove_smiles(":()") == ")");
    assert(remove_smiles("AA:)))BB:(") == "AABB");
    assert(remove_smiles("::)(XX") == ":(XX");
    assert(remove_smiles(":)):))X") == "X");
    assert(remove_smiles(":():))") == ")");
}
```

Comment: If you truly meant to modify in-place, then your function should accept a _reference_ to a string, rather than making a copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Avoid `using namespace std`

While `using namespace std` can save you a little bit of typing, it brings *everything* from the `std` namespace into the global namespace, including things you did not think of. It is safer to [avoid doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), or only to use it on a more restricted set of things. For example, if you would use `std::string` a lot, you can write:

```
using std::string;
```

## Make use of the fact that `std::string`s are NUL-terminated

It's great that you thought about bounds checking.
However, since C++11, `std::string`s are guaranteed to have a NUL-byte at the end. You can make use of this fact and simplify your code a bit:

```
if (s[i] == ':' and (s[i + 1] == ')' or s[i + 1] == '(')) {
    int j = i + 1;
    char smile_mode = s[j];
    while (s[j] == smile_mode) {
        ++j;
    }
    i = j - 1;
}
```

This may or may not result in slightly more optimal code.

## Consider using `find()`, `find_first_not_of()` and `copy()`

You are going through the input string character by character. For small strings this is probably fine, but for larger strings there are more optimal ways to search of a given character, like by reading multiple bytes at a time and using vector instructions. While you could try to implement such an algorithm yourself, the standard library might have implemented these already. Consider rewriting your algorithm in a way that leverages standard functions like `std::string`'s [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`find_first_not_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of). With `find()` you can find the next occurence of `':'`, and then when you have `smile_mode`, you can use `find_first_not_of()` to find the first character that is no longer part of the smile. Once you know which part to copy, use the [`copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy) member function to copy a whole range of characters in one go.

Comment: thank you for the review